# Wich method is faster for fetch data in IPFS

Tags: nodejs, ipfs

I got a site that fetchs data from ipfs network i am currently using it with axios.get("http://ipfs.io/ipfs...") and sometimes the blockchain is really slow, so i dont know is there another way to fetch fatest this data.

Maybe getting it directly with the ipfs protocol, how to do it using nodejs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IPFS has nothing to do with a blockchain. It's a peer to peer file system. The host ipfs.io though is often overused so it can be slow.

I would try a different IPFS provider such as Cloudflare or infura.io (https://infura-ipfs.io/ipfs/). Be aware that they're often rate limited so better to probably role your own IPFS node.

If you want to connect to a different node via nodejs, then here's some code that might help:

```
import { create } from 'ipfs-http-client';
const fs = require('fs');

// and then call the below function
async function getIpfsFileAsArchive(ipfs, cid){
    for await (const buf of ipfs.get(cid, {archive: true, compress: true})) {
        const ipfs = await create({host: "replace with ipfs host ip address"});
        fs.createWriteStream(`./ipfs/${cid}.tar.gz`).write(buf);
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you will use this to get it dono i think this is the right answer, thanks